# Name resolution for class definition blocks and arguments to exec() and eval()

Tags: python, python-3.x

From https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names

> A class deﬁnition is an executable statement that may use and deﬁne
>   names. These references follow **the normal rules** for name
>   resolution with an exception that **unbound local variables are
>   looked up in the global namespace.**

What does "unbound local variables are looked up in the global namespace" mean here?  Can a class definition be inside another class definition or a function definition, so that the lookup of an unbound local variable is not in the global namespace but in a local nesting scope?

What are "the normal rules"?

Thanks.

Comment: Your link provides an example; in class `A`, the assignment to `b` fails because the list comprehension uses `a` which is defined as a class attribute, but not in the global scope.

Comment: The example doesn't answer my questions, but explains something else: "The scope of names deﬁned in a class block is limited
to the class block; it does not extend to the code blocks of methods – this includes comprehensions and generator
expressions since they are implemented using a function scope."

Comment: `a` is an unbound local variable inside the generator expression (not list comprehension, sorry, my mistake), but the `class` statement doesn't create a scope. Thus, the enclosing scope for the generator is not the class, but the global scope, so the assignment to `A.a` is not seen by the generator expression.

Answer (score 2):

Take this example:

```
x = 1
def foo():
    x = 2
    class Bar:
        print(x)
        x = 3
foo()
# Output: 1
```

When `print()` is called, `x` is local (because it's assigned in the next line), but still unbound because it's used before it's assigned a value.

You might expect that the unbound `x` is looked up in the closest namespace (which would be `2`), but in class blocks, *"unbound local variables are looked up in the global namespace"*, so the global `x` is looked up and `1` is printed.

---

Let's remove the assignment inside `Bar`:

```
x = 1
def foo():
    x = 2
    class Bar:
        print(x)
foo()
# Output: 2
```

Now we're following the *"normal rules of name resolution"* and get the output `2`, because the `x` inside `Bar` is not local anymore (it's a *free* variable) and looked up in the nearest enclosing scope.

---

Also, the rule to look up unbound locals in the local namespace is for classes, but not for functions. Let's try it with a function:

```
x = 1
def foo():
    x = 2
    def bar():
        print(x)
        x = 3
    bar()
foo()
# Raises: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

As you can see, in a function you can't use a local before assigning a value to it.